# Why can I not push data into labels?

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js

I am using Vue2 and ChartJs.
I have a set of array which look like this:

[image]

I have no issues pushing lossEmptyUnits to my dataset, but I also need to push the date to my labels so that I can try to sort the array by month, but for some reason I cannot get it to work. If I leave labels as an empty array and try to push the date field into it, then nothing happens.
Any suggestions?

My code:

```js
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      chartData: {
        height: '400px',
        type: 'bar',
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: 'green'
          } ],

      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
      },
      options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                suggestedMax: 0,
                callback: value => this.$n(value)
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created(){
    biService.getBIGraphStatsForCompany()
        .then(result => result.data.propertyStatsPerMonth.forEach(field => this.chartData.datasets[0].data.push(field.lossEmptyUnits)))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.5/vue.js"></script>
```

What I tried:

```js
created(){
    biService.getBIGraphStatsForCompany()
        .then(result => result.data.propertyStatsPerMonth.forEach(field => this.chartData.datasets[0].data.push(field.lossEmptyUnits)))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    biService.getBIGraphStatsForCompany()
        .then(result => result.data.propertyStatsPerMonth.forEach(field => this.chartData.labels[0].push(field.date)))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to push labels to `this.chartData.labels` instead of `this.chartData.labels[0]`.

```js
created(){
    biService.getBIGraphStatsForCompany()
        .then(result => result.data.propertyStatsPerMonth.forEach(field => {
            this.chartData.datasets[0].data.push(field.lossEmptyUnits)
            this.chartData.labels.push(field.date)
        }))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```